Labels of sunburst chart in ant design chart are not working correctly
Sunburst chart labels do not work properly when the label display points are in the wrong position in the chart.
Here is the library and configuration code:
import { Sunburst } from "@ant-design/plots";

const sunburstChartConfig = {
  animate: {
    enter: { type: "waveIn" },
  },

  tooltip: {
    title: "name",
    items: [{ channel: "value", field: "value" }],
  },

  style: {
    fillOpacity: (props) => (props.depth === 2 ? 0.7 : 1),
  },
  label: {
    position: "outside",
  },
  innerRadius: 0,
};

Here is label of sunburst chart with my configuration
Here is the label that shows the image of the exact Pie Chart
Can anyone help me fix it?
